# BQ→データポータルの更新について

Tags: google-bigquery

データポータルなのでここでの質問が適切かわかりませんが、、。
BQに入ってきたデータを、リアルタイムにデータポータルに表示させる
やり方がわかりません。知っている方がおられましたら、教えてください！

Answer (score 0):

データポータルのヘルプに記載されている通りに設定するだけで、データポータルでBigQueryテーブルのデータを参照できます。

- https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6370296?hl=ja
- https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6295968?hl=ja

データデータポータルで参照するデータはキャッシュされます。キャッシュについては、下記をご確認ください。
https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7020039

「リアルタイム」という要件が正確にどういったことなのかはわかりませんが、データポータルでレポートデータを手動で更新（キャッシュの手動更新）できますので、現時点のBigQueryテーブルのデータを参照できます。